# Magento 2 Cloud - Upload SQL script file to server and import into custom database table

Tags: magento2, magento2-cloud

I'm trying to import a SQL script file into a Magento cloud database.

The script file has about 83k lines of insert statements and it populates one table in the database.

**My current progress:**

I managed to connect to the remote database using ssh tunneling as explained in the Magento Cloud docs [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/env/environments-ssh.html#env-start-tunn).

The problem I'm facing is the ssh tunnel connection takes about 3 minutes to complete 800 inserts. You can imagine how long this process will take.

**Question:**

I would like to know if there is a way for me to upload the SQL script to the remote server and run the import via the CLI instead, which will be faster.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:

I managed to figure this out myself.

Using the Command: `magento-cloud sql < dump.sql` i was able to run the import in under a minute.

Also you can use the `magento-cloud scp` command.

See `magento-cloud scp --help` for more information